# I cant load a Wordpress page. I get POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [HTTP/2 500 Internal Server Error]

Tags: ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, http-status-code-500

I have a portal page that is stuck on the preloader. In the Inspector, it throws this error:

```
POST https://####/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php[HTTP/2 500 Internal Server Error 5675ms]
```

Below that, there is these error messages:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Version: HTTP/2
Transferred: 726 B (241 B size)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

RESPONSE HEADERS

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://####
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 30 Oct 2022 08:45:32 GMT
expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
server: Apache
x-content-type-options: nosniff
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-robots-tag: noindex
```

REQUEST HEADERS

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1242
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: wordpress_sec_43463c74c2bcdfa8f63c308437d1e9a2=########.com%7C1668185768%7C3RDSuJIwsueKkV0XMKCFD8aYWn14tchxzW5ygy5ZT2V%7Cc98e394e223dbf6e592589722ee40693641c42b27df660dc8bf0d307d26d1bb8; wordpress_logged_in_43463c74c2bcdfa8f63c308437d1e9a2=rreis%40ejme.com%7C1668185768%7C3RDSuJIwsueKkV0XMKCFD8aYWn14tchxzW5ygy5ZT2V%7Caa83aa2070723dd4047efdf67a1d3681a827359dfac09e97fe3ebf5156f6c343; wp-settings-175=editor%3Dtinymce; wp-settings-time-175=1666975646; wpc_key=BcD%26y9QHSMt%21mygJDcMm; PHPSESSID=ac2505ebc1aa49f5748064cb9bbfc233; sc_is_visitor_unique=rx11212407.1667119532.8D619E70C6CF4F2F03D9DB342E78DFB3.2.2.2.2.2.2.2.1.1
Host: www.####.co.uk
Origin: https://www.####.co.uk
Referer: https://www.####.co.uk/portal/portal-hub/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
TE: trailers
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Can anybody tell what is throwing the error? And is this why the page wont load?

Thanks

Comment: a 500 message within an ajax call means something went obvious wrong. What does server log say? It will track what error caused the ajax-admin to throw an error.

Comment: This is what my error log shows:

`[Sat Oct 29 21:13:57.750784 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 994969:tid 47151224387328] [client 57.128.19.189:56236] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/algarve1/public_html/wp-includes/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.php,index.phtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Comment: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cannot-serve-directory-home-public_html-no-matching-directoryindex-index-html-index-php-found-and-server-genera.687813/ see here

Comment: Thanks @Dorvalla, I checked that out and made sure there was an index file in the root folder (public_html/index.html) but it looks like its definitely ajax error. I am really stuck with this one.